# Multi-boot external M.2 NVMe drive

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, nvme

I recently bought an M.2 NVMe drive and enclosure with the intent of setting it up as an external drive that is able to boot from a selection of multiple ISOs (predominantly Linux ISOs, with some Windows ones sprinkled in); whether it be a live OS or an OS installer (a lot of the time these are one and the same, but not always).

After a couple of days of trying a handful of different apps, I'm at my wits end. The are the multi-boot drive creation apps I've tried with no success:

- Sardu v3.4.3
- YUMI v2.0.8.6
- MultiBootUSB v9.2.0
- XBoot v1.0 beta14
- WinSetupFromUSB v1.9

It seemed like YUMI was going to be the most promising, but it won't recognise the NVMe drive (nor will a lot of the other apps, except for Sardu). From my research it appears that this is because YUMI only recognises drives that Windows sees as a USB drive, as opposed to a "Local Disk" (which is how the NVMe drive is being identified by Windows).

The problem with Sardu is that it supposedly creates the bootable drive, but none of the machines I've tested it on have either recognised it as a boot device, or been able to boot from it even if it does recognise it. I've tried using an actual USB drive with no success, so I don't think it's the NVMe drive that's causing the issue with Sardu.

Has anyone succeeded in creating a multi-boot external NVMe drive? How did you do it?

Comment: Windows doesn’t like being booted from an external disk unless it’s a Windows 2 Go installation. I am assuming you haven’t tried that, Windows 2 Go is no longer supported by Microsoft, but Rufus still supports it.  Additionally, Windows 2 Go installs cannot be updated.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not trying to boot Windows Live from the external drive (I want to be able to boot into the windows installer though, as you would normally with bootable Windows media), so Windows to go isn't suitable for my purpose anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested I check out Easy2Boot (https://www.easy2boot.com/).

So far this has worked absolutely beautifully.

For anyone else's future reference, this YouTube video steps you through the process of setting up an E2B drive very clearly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6wbTAazfv0